# How do I plot multiple data subset forecast predictions onto a single plot

Tags: r, plot, forecasting

I am new to R and have found this site extremely helpful, so here is my first posted question.  I appreciate your assistance and acknowledge the wisdom on this site.

**Background:**  Start with 5 years of weekly sales data to develop a forecast for future production based on weekly sales with a very strong year seasonality.  Determined the starting point with:

```
auto.fit <- auto.arima(arima.ts, stepwise=FALSE, parallel=TRUE, num.cores=6, trace=TRUE )
> ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,1)[52] with drift.
```

Now I wish to certify the accuracy with visual plotting of multiple 'windows' into the data and compare to the actual values. (This included logging the AIC values.)  In other words, the function loops through the data at programmed intervals recomputing/plotting the forecast onto the same plot.  It plotted correctly when my window started at the head of the data.  Now I am looking at a moving 104 week window and the results are all overlaid starting at 104th observation.

```
require(forecast)   ##[EDITED for simplified clarity]

data <- rep(cos(1:52*(3.1416/26)),5)*100+1000+c(1:26,25:0)

# Create the current fit on data and predict one year out
plot(data, type="l", xlab="weeks", ylab="counts",main="Overlay forecasts & actuals",
     sub="green=FIT(1-105,by 16) wks back & PREDICT(26) wks, blue=52 wks")
result <- tryCatch({
  arima.fit <- auto.arima(tail(data,156)) 
  arima.pred <- predict(arima.fit, n.ahead=52)
  lines(arima.pred$pred, col="blue")
  lines(arima.pred$pred+2*arima.pred$se, col="red")
  lines(arima.pred$pred-2*arima.pred$se, col="red")
}, error = function(e) {return(e$message)} )  ## Trap error

# Loop and perform comparison plotting of forecast to actuals
for (j in seq(1,105,by=16)) { 
  result <- tryCatch({
    ############## This plotted correctly as "Arima(head(data,-j),..."
    arima1.fit <- auto.arima(head(tail(data,-j),156))
    arima1.pred <- predict(arima1.fit, n.ahead=52)
    lines(arima1.pred$pred, col="green", lty=(numtests %% 6) + 1 )
  }, error = function(e) {return(e$message)}) ## Trap errors
}
```

The plots were accurate when all the forecasting included the head of the file, however, the AIC was not comparable between forecast windows because the sample size kept shrinking.

**Question:** How do I show the complete 5 years of sales data and overlay forecasts at programmed intervals which are computed from a rolling window of 3 years (156 observations)?

The AIC values logged are comparable using the rolling window approach, but all the forecasts overlay starting at observation 157.  I tried making the data into a time series and found the initial data plotted correctly on a time axis, but the forecasts were not time series, so they did not display.

Comment: The usual answer would be `?lines`, but I will admit that time series function in R can be kind of strange.

Comment: @DWin The 'lines()' does not offer an offset for the plot positioning.  (I am also trying this as a ts object, but this post is to understand how to offset numeric data to the plot)  Do you know where I can learn 'what is under the hood' in the forecast data?  How does it know to plot the forecast data starting at 1 observation past the length of the fit data?  If I knew that, then I can intervene and plot it where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in another post [Is there an easy way to revert a forecast back into a time series for plotting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137745/is-there-an-easy-way-to-revert-a-forecast-back-into-a-time-series-for-plotting)

This was initially posted as two unique questions, but they have the same answer.

The core question being addressed is "how to restore the original time stamps to the forecast data". What I have learned with trial and error is "configure, then never loose the time series attribute" by applying these steps:

**1: Make a time series** Use the ts() command and create a time series.
**2: Subset a time series** Use 'window()' to create a subset of the time series in 'for()' loop. Use 'start()' and 'end()' on the data to show the time axis positions.
**3: Forecast a time series** Use 'forecast()' or 'predict()' which operate on time series.
**4: Plot a time series** When you plot a time series, then the time axis will align correctly for additional data using the lines() command. {Plotting options are user preference.}

The forecasts will plot over the historical data in the correct time axis location.

The code is here: [Is there an easy way to revert a forecast back into a time series for plotting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137745/is-there-an-easy-way-to-revert-a-forecast-back-into-a-time-series-for-plotting)